# Cannot set image data to hidden field, while using Pica with Cropit

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to implement client side resize and crop of images using [Cropit](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit) with [Pica](https://github.com/nodeca/pica). In the following code I'm trying to set data created by pica to a hidden form field and than submit that form to a php file to show that data as an image, when I do it the normal canvas way, it works, but when i try to do it through pica it doesn't work, following is the code for both the cases.

**1. The following code implements it through normal canvas and it works.**

**HTML:**

```
<form action="http://localhost/img_upload/image/upload" id="input-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="image-editor">
            <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">
            <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
            <div class="image-size-label">
              Drag Slider to zoom
        </div>
        <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
        <input type="hidden" name="image-data" class="hidden-image-data" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

**Jquery:**

```
  $(function() { 
    $('.image-editor').cropit();

    $('#input-form').submit(function() {

      // Move cropped image data to hidden input
      var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export', {type: 'image/jpeg',quality: .75});
      $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageData);

      // don't submit the form if the imageData is empty
      // for example if user is clicking on the submit without loading an image
      if (imageData == null) {
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
```

**2. The following code tries to implement it through pica and fails.**

**HTML:**

```
<form action="http://localhost/img_upload/image/upload" id="input-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <div class="image-editor">
      <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">
      <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
      <div class="image-size-label">
        Drag slider to zoom
      </div>
      <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
      <input type="hidden" name="image-data" class="hidden-image-data">
      <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Jquery:**

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var $editor = $('.image-editor');
    $editor.cropit();

    $('#input-form').submit(function() {
      // Get cropping information
      var imgSrc = $editor.cropit('imageSrc');
      var offset = $editor.cropit('offset');
      var zoom = $editor.cropit('zoom');
      var previewSize = $editor.cropit('previewSize');
      var exportZoom = $editor.cropit('exportZoom');

      var img = new Image();
      img.src = imgSrc;

      // Draw image in original size on a canvas
      var originalCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      originalCanvas.width = previewSize.width / zoom;
      originalCanvas.height = previewSize.height / zoom;
      var ctx = originalCanvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(img, offset.x / zoom, offset.y / zoom);

      // Use pica to resize image and paint on destination canvas
      var zoomedCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      zoomedCanvas.width = previewSize.width * exportZoom;
      zoomedCanvas.height = previewSize.height * exportZoom;
      pica.resizeCanvas(originalCanvas, zoomedCanvas, {
        // Pica options, see https://github.com/nodeca/pica


      }, function(err) {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }

        // Resizing completed
        // Read resized image data
        var picaImageData = zoomedCanvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', .75);
        $('.hidden-image-data').val(picaImageData);

      });

      if (picaImageData == null) {
        return false;
      }

    });
  });
```

Here is the controller (which is the same for both the cases).
Note: I'm using codeigniter for this test.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Image extends CI_Controller {

  public function index()
  {
    $this->load->view('upload_form');
  }

  public function upload()
  {
    $image = $this->input->post('image-data');
    echo "<img src='$image'>";
  }

}
```

---

---

*Edit: this is what the maintainer of Pica commented when I asked the same question at github.*

> *" Pica is async. Your current implementation of submit will end before pica return data. That's a generic question, not related to
>   pica anyhow. "*

---

---

Any help will be appreciated.

**Thank You.**

Comment: @sjm No it doesn't give any error message, but the result page (where I want to print the resulted image) is empty in case of pica while in case of normal canvas resize it shows the result.

Comment: @sjm let me update the question and add the controller also. You saw the view files for both the cases already.